# Problem resolving type dependency when using ts-loader, but not with tsc

Tags: typescript, redux, ts-loader

I am trying to migrate a single file from a large existing react/redux project to Typescript. I am having trouble solving the error on the following line of code :

`import {Dispatch} from 'redux';`

The error is the following :

```
      TS2305: Module '"../node_modules/redux/es/redux"' has no exported member 'Dispatch'.
```

I can confirm that the file `../node_modules/redux/index.d.ts` does exist and contains the exported interface declaration I am trying to import.

How can I further debug or solve this kind of issue?

EDIT 1 : I have also discovered that I can invoke `./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc --esModuleInterop true --jsx "react" myFile.tsx` successfully. It is only when compiling through `webpack 4` and `ts-loader 7` that the problem presents itself.

Comment: How are you importing this?

Comment: @Evert : The import is done like this : `import {Dispatch} from 'redux';`